# PyQT progress bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have got a code for scanning files and finding duplicates in them. I need to add a progress bar to show a scanning process to the user. I've tried different variations, but all I got was a progress bar which shows only 0% and then immediately 100%. I couldn't connect my progress bar to my scanning progress.

There is the code:

```
import sys
import os
import time
from collections import defaultdict
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QTreeWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QProgressBar, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QTimer, pyqtSignal

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.inputLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.inputLayout.setObjectName("inputLayout")
        self.directoryLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.directoryLabel.setObjectName("directoryLabel")
        self.inputLayout.addWidget(self.directoryLabel)
        self.directoryLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.directoryLineEdit.setObjectName("directoryLineEdit")
        self.inputLayout.addWidget(self.directoryLineEdit)
        self.browseButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.browseButton.setObjectName("browseButton")
        self.inputLayout.addWidget(self.browseButton)
        self.scanButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.scanButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.scanButton.setObjectName("scanButton")
        self.inputLayout.addWidget(self.scanButton)
        self.stopButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.stopButton.setVisible(False)
        self.stopButton.setObjectName("stopButton")
        self.inputLayout.addWidget(self.stopButton)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.inputLayout)
        self.treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName("treeWidget")
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, "File's name")
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(1, "Size")
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(2, "Folder")
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(3, "Path")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.treeWidget)
        self.statusLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.statusLayout.setObjectName("statusLayout")
        self.statusbar1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar1.setObjectName("statusbar1")
        self.statusLayout.addWidget(self.statusbar1)
        self.statusbar2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar2.setObjectName("statusbar2")
        self.statusLayout.addWidget(self.statusbar2)
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setVisible(False)
        self.statusLayout.addWidget(self.progressBar)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.statusLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File Dublicate Scanner"))
        self.directoryLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Directory:"))
        self.browseButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Review"))
        self.scanButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Scan"))
        self.stopButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop"))

class ScanThread(QThread):
    update_progress = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    scan_complete = QtCore.pyqtSignal(defaultdict)

    def __init__(self, directory, parent=None):
        self.directory = directory
        self.stop_requested = False
        super(ScanThread, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        file_sizes = defaultdict(list)
        total_files = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(self.directory)])
        current_file = 0
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.directory):
            if self.stop_requested:
                break
            for file in files:
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
                file_sizes[file_size].append((file_path, os.path.basename(root), file))
                current_file += 1
                progress = (current_file / total_files) * 100
                self.update_progress.emit(progress)
            if self.stop_requested:
                break

        if not self.stop_requested:
            self.scan_complete.emit(file_sizes)

    def stop(self):
        self.stop_requested = True

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.progress_value = 0
        self.scan_thread = None
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_progress_ui)
        self.timer.start(100)

        self.browseButton.clicked.connect(self.browse)
        self.scanButton.clicked.connect(self.scan)
        self.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.stop_scan)
        self.directoryLineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.enable_scan_button)


    def format_file_size(self, size):
        if size < 1024 * 1024:
            return f"{size / 1024:.2f} KB"
        else:
            return f"{size / 1024 / 1024:.2f} MB"

    def browse(self):
        directory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory()
        if directory:
            self.directoryLineEdit.setText(directory)

    def enable_scan_button(self):
        if self.directoryLineEdit.text():
            self.scanButton.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.scanButton.setEnabled(False)

    def paste_from_clipboard(self):
        clipboard = QtWidgets.QApplication.clipboard().text()
        if os.path.isdir(clipboard):
            self.directoryLineEdit.setText(clipboard)

    def scan(self):
        directory = self.directoryLineEdit.text()
        if directory:
            self.treeWidget.clear()
            self.statusbar1.clear()
            self.statusbar2.clear()
            self.progressBar.setMaximum(100)
            self.progressBar.setValue(0)
            self.progressBar.setVisible(True)
            self.scanButton.setVisible(False)
            self.stopButton.setVisible(True)
            self.scan_thread = ScanThread(directory)
            self.scan_thread.update_progress.connect(self.store_progress_value)
            self.scan_thread.scan_complete.connect(self.on_scan_complete)
            self.scan_thread.start()

    def stop_scan(self):
        if self.scan_thread:
            self.scan_thread.stop()
            self.stopButton.setVisible(False)
            self.scanButton.setVisible(True)

    def on_update_progress(self, progress, file_path, file_name):
        self.progress_value = int(progress)
        self.statusbar1.setText(f"Scan: {file_name}")
        self.statusbar2.setText(f"Path: {file_path}")
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()

    def store_progress_value(self, progress):
        self.progress_value = progress

    def update_progress_ui(self):
        self.progressBar.setValue(self.progress_value)

    def on_scan_complete(self, file_sizes):
        self.progressBar.setValue(100)
        self.progressBar.setVisible(False)
        self.statusbar1.clear()
        self.statusbar2.clear()

        duplicates = 0
        duplicates_size = 0
        for size, files in file_sizes.items():
            if len(files) > 1:
                duplicates += len(files) - 1
                duplicates_size += (len(files) - 1) * size

        total_files = sum(len(files) for files in file_sizes.values())
        duplicates_percentage = (duplicates / total_files) * 100

        self.statusbar1.setText(f"Total Files: {total_files}, Dublicate Amount: {duplicates}")
        self.statusbar2.setText(
            f"Dublicate Size: {self.format_file_size(duplicates_size)}, Dublicate Percentage: {duplicates_percentage:.2f}%")

        for size, files in file_sizes.items():
            if len(files) > 1:
                original = QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
                original.setText(0, files[0][2])
                original.setText(1, self.format_file_size(size))
                original.setText(2, files[0][1])
                original.setText(3, files[0][0])
                for duplicate in files[1:]:
                    dup = QTreeWidgetItem(original)
                    dup.setText(0, duplicate[2])
                    dup.setText(1, self.format_file_size(size))
                    dup.setText(2, duplicate[1])
                    dup.setText(3, duplicate[0])
                self.treeWidget.expandItem(original)

        self.treeWidget.collapseAll()

        self.stopButton.setVisible(False)
        self.scanButton.setVisible(True)



    def signal_accept(self, msg):

        self.pbar.setValue(int(msg))
        if self.pbar.value() == 100:
            self.pbar.setValue(0)
            self.btn.setEnabled(True)


class Thread(QThread):
    _signal = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super(Thread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        for i in range(101):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self._signal.emit(i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I dont know PyQt 5 very much, so I've basically tried to just copy some progress bars from the internet and connect them to my code.

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine however there is a little mistake that makes the code not working.
You define update progress as pyQtSignal that will send an int into the ScanThread class

```py
 update_progress = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
```

However, the value you emit (the progress variable) is a float

```py
progress = (current_file / total_files) * 100 # This is a float
```

So when you emit a float in a signal that is supposed to emit an integer , the value of the emitted signal has no sense and the value of the pyqt progress bar can't be update as it is not between 0 and 100.

To fix your problem simply cast your progress value into an int like this :

```py
progress = int((current_file / total_files) * 100) # This will make your code work
```

I hope my explanation will help you understand the mistake.